# High Resolution cycle counter for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, arm

I recently got a Raspberry pi Model B+. I intend on benchmarking the board, and hence was trying to find a solution which is similar to "rtdsc". According to the following article, i can access the high resolution cycle counter register in the Raspberry pi. I am stuck on how to use the following module. I do not know how to execute it on the Raspberry pi.

http://blog.regehr.org/archives/794

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to write a kernel module (the current kernel is 3.18.x) which you'd possibly need to update at each kernel change.  Isn't microsecond precision good enough?  Just run your benchmarks a bit longer.